# getting null Graph fields from spark map operation after collect

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark

Using Java + Scala with apache Spark.
I have some String data in javaRDDs (`textdata` variable) which I convert to scala graphs using a helper class :

```
SparkConf = new SparkConf(true); // also set parameters, etc
JavaSparkContext sc =  new JavaSparkContext(conf);
JavaRDD<Graph<String, Object>> graphs = textdata.map(new GraphConverterClass(JavaSparkContext.toSparkContext(sc)));

List<Graph<String,Object>> graphsList = graphs.collect();
```

The converter class implements the Function interface, so it has a call :

```
public Graph<String, Object> call(String data)
{
 Graph<String,object> mygraph = someFunc(data,sc);
 return mygraph;
}
```

When I run this, inside the converter class I can see the `mygraph` result and it's fine.

In the list I collect at the driver program however, despite the number of graphs being correct, the vertices and edges fields of each is null.

Using another dummy class instead of Graph in the scenario above works fine, i.e., the values of its fields are retained.

So why are the graph objects not collected properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that `textData` is an RDD, using a `map` function that closes over the SparkContext is not supported.

The SparkContext is an object that lives exclusively in the driver and it is 'null' on the executors. (it's surprising that it doesn't give a `SerializationException`)

The same issue can be spotted at the type of the result of that operation:
`JavaRDD<Graph<String, Object>>`  Nested  RDDs are conceptually undefined.

One possible solution is to rethink the process in terms of creating Vertices and Edges RDDs and using the `Graph` constructor to build the target graph.

Comment: I declared the spark context as `private static transient SparkContext sc;` in the converter class and pass it from the driver as an argument. Is it still a problem if it's transient => not serialized ?

Comment: In addition, the spark context is not null in the converter class method. The graph in there is fine, I just can't get it to the driver intact.